# NSUserDefaults written in -applicationWillTerminate: do not take effect; Why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have put the code below inside my AppDelegate, but when I start the app again I notice that the values are still saved (Not NULL). Why is that?

The code:

```
    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:NULL forKey:@"roomCat"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:NULL forKey:@"TFA"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        setObject:NULL forKey:@"comments"];

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `-removeObjectForKey:` instead of setting `NULL`. The former is the official way to remove values, while the latter is undocumented behavior.

In any case, if using `-removeObjectForKey:` doesn't work, then you can add a call to

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

at the end. But only do that if it doesn't work without it. The reason being because calling `-synchronize` is (relatively) expensive, so it should only be done when required to ensure correctness.

---

After taking another look, I suspect your real problem is this method isn't being called at all. On iOS 4 and later, when apps enter the background, they don't call this method, instead they call `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`. You should try putting this code there instead.

Comment: I am charging my iPhone right now but i tried your code on the simulator and nothing changes hope the code will work in the real device

Comment: @Bobj-C: See my edited answer. It's probably not being called at all. Incidentally, why are you removing user defaults when your app quits? The whole point of `NSUserDefaults` is to persist settings across app launches.

Comment: @KevinBallard Excellent answer, this should definitely work. I also don't understand why you would want to wipe them before leaving. It just doesn't make sense. :\

Comment: @Bobj-C: Note that if you want to be sure this code executes when the user leaves your app, you should actually perform this work in both `-applicationWillTerminate:` and `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` (put it in a method that's called from both spots), because there are still rare situations where `-applicationWillTerminate:` can be called.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I would expect that you would need to manually call the synchronize method on NSUserDefaults as the last line in this method to ensure it syncs before the application terminates.

Comment: Just to add to this, in iOS 4 and above "applicationWillTerminate:" is called very rarely. It would be better to use "applicationDidEnterBackground:". :)

Answer (score 0):

try this method instead:

```
- (void)removeObjectForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


 if (prefs) 
{

    [prefs setObject:NULL forKey:@"roomCat"];
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```